# Allowed length of tag excerpt in static box is too short compared to one in excerpt popup

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-excerpt

As you can see on the screenshot excerpt ends with words "Use this tag if your question is related to ...". Then it suggests to click "learn more..." and one is being redirected to tag wiki, but tag wiki often starts with something different and you have to hover the mouse over the tag anyway to see complete text.

I think tag excerpts are so short that complete text should appear in the box. This would expand the box by maybe one additional line.

edit: such shortening may sometimes produce weird results and confuse users. Imagine [ico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ico) tag excerpt would be cut in different place producing sentence

> Do not use this tag for general questions about icons or concepts such as "favicon"...

instead of

> Do not use this tag for general questions about icons or concepts such as "favicon" if you don't plan to use ICO format for them.
>   .

Or imagine `python` tag excerpt ending with words `Don't use this tag when asking about Python...` learn more... `snake`.

[image: Screenshot presenting ICO tag excerpt.]

---

BTW instead of or in addition to displaying **About** [tag-excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag-excerpt) on [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ico/info), I would show tag excerpt in the form similar to the box, which is visible above questions, only without links `"learn more.. | improve tag wiki | ..."` and of course with full text, not shortened one.

---

Hmmm. Any chance this feature will be implemented? It doesn't look like it would take more than 15 minutes to implement, but it would improve user experience substantially.