# Are tag excerpts too long or am I just in a hurry to get off the elevator?

Tags: discussion, tag-excerpt

Many of us have read the [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/) where tag excerpts were compared to elevator pitches:

> The excerpt is the elevator pitch for the tag. You only have ~500 plain text characters for the excerpt, so don't feel obligated to cover everything in it! Save that for the 30,000+ character Markdown tag wiki. The excerpt should define the shared quality of questions containing this tag -- boiled down to a few short sentences.

The problem is: if I was on an elevator with some of our tag excerpts, I'd see about getting off as soon as I could.

They're just too long. This seems to affect all of the big tags.

According to [some random website,](https://pitchinggreatness.wordpress.com/2013/04/16/elevator-pitch-how-long-should-your-pitch-be/) elevator pitches can range from anywhere from a few seconds up to 90 seconds. Here's one of the guidelines:

> The 30 seconds or less pitch includes pitches from just a few seconds to half a minute.  These pitches are often a person’s or group of people’s first interaction with the person, business, product or service.

That just about sums up what tag excerpts are for. They are supposed to make it easier to tag things, especially for non-experts.

What's crazy is that these tag "excerpts" are longer than the average post made by a new user (if you exclude their huge dump of code, of course)!

I suspect that even when new users realize that something special happens when they roll over tags, they don't have the attention span to read it (I usually don't).

The excerpts seem to be too long for the system, too: [Allowed length of tag excerpt in static box is too short compared to one in excerpt popup](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262675)

Many of these tag excerpts dedicate precious space to things that I don't consider to be very important (for a tag excerpt). Let's look at [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java):

> Java is a general-purpose object-oriented programming language designed to be used in conjunction with the Java Virtual Machine (JVM). "Java platform" is the name for a computing system that has installed tools for developing and running Java programs. Use this tag for questions referring to Java programming language or Java platform tools. (Note that Java is not to be confused with JavaScript)

By the time I reach the hyphen (after the fourth word), my attention is already lost. How does reading that first sentence help me ask a Java question? Same with the second one. It's not until the THIRD line that there is any usage guideline.

Here's [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex):

> Regular expressions provide a declarative language to match patterns within strings. They are commonly used for string validation, parsing, and transformation. Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.

I could have asked and answered an entire question about regexes in the space that the excerpt takes up. I also find it incredibly dense and challenging to read despite the fact that I am a native English speaker with an interest in regexes.

I suspect that part of the problem is that many of these tag excerpts are either plagiarized off Wikipedia or the company's website, or they are written in such a way that they might as well have been plagiarized.

I can't be the only one getting off at the next floor, right? Shouldn't we do something about this? Or am I misunderstanding something about how tag excerpts work?

Comment: The problem is that most people use tag excerpts as definitions of what the tag means, which would be ok if it was a obscure tag (kind of a reminder), instead of saying how they should be used.

Comment: Tag excerpts should be for 2 things.  Tell me (very briefly) what the tag is for.  And tell me how/when to use it.  Anything else should be in the tag wiki page.

Comment: I would say that the java excerpt can just be "Use this tag for questions referring to Java programming language or Java platform tools. (Note that Java is not to be confused with JavaScript)". Most sane people would know what to do.

Comment: You should not use an elevator. Use the stairs instead. (Oh, that is not what this question was about...)

Comment: Does anybody actually read tag excerpts?

Comment: I want your fast elevators.

Comment: This reads more like a rant than a question.

Comment: @TravisJ I wrote this a while ago, (and tried to keep it as up-beat as possible), but it's a little hard when you encounter these issues with tag excepts CONSTANTLY. In retrospect, there are plenty of tag excerpts that are way poorer than the two I picked out.

Answer (score 2):

The tag excerpt should give you guidance on how to use the tag. And in these examples, they do.

Let's say you shorten the Java tag (as suggested in the comments):

> Use this tag for questions referring to Java programming language or Java platform tools. (Note that Java is not to be confused with JavaScript)

If someone wants to ask a question about Java, he likely already knows that it is a programming language. But what about "Java platform tools"? At least that should be explained. And it turns out, it *is* explained in a very clear way in the preceding sentence we just have cut from the excerpt.

There are some tags where it isn't immediately obvious for what the tag *actually* is. It's simply good practice to explain what the tag is for.

Say I'm using something called "foo" and find a tag "foo". If the only thing in the tag except is "This tag is used for questions about `foo`, for questions about bar use the "bar" tag", then I still don't know if what I think "foo" is is the kind of "foo" the tag is for. If the tag excerpt reads "`foo` is a Linux command line utility related to ..." then I immediately know that this isn't the "foo" tag I'm looking for when the "foo" I'm using is a JavaScript library and the tag usually used for it is "js-foo".

So no, those tag excerpts are not too long. They are *accurate* enough to make the user aware what the tag is about and when to use it, but not too long in my opinion. *You* might already know what Java is, but that doesn't mean it shouldn't be explained for everyone else.

Comment: In other words: One skims a tag wiki for a relevant word, rather than reading it in detail. If I ask a question about the javascript library foo, I skim the tag wiki for "javascript" and "library", rather than reading it word by word.

Comment: @Sumurai8 That is very true and I would do the same. But I don't think it is appropriate to only have a collection of buzz words in a tag. I mean, how would that look like? `linux, command line, use for foo`? That is certainly not a good tag excerpt. Just because you can and would not read it in certain situations (hell, I've often just skimmed whole publications while searching something) doesn't mean it shouldn't be well written to begin with.

Comment: "*don't feel obligated to cover everything in it! Save that for the 30,000+ character Markdown tag wiki*" -- Is there a reason why this should be in the **excerpt** instead of the **wiki**?

Comment: I  feel the excerpt is a bit like an abstract in a paper. It should be short, concise and self-contained. If you cut too much, then the excerpt suddenly can not be understood without referring to the whole wiki. And that defeats its purpose.